# Pass the event to the _.throttle function using jQuery 'on' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

How am I suppose to pass the event to the _.throttle function. I need to pass the id of the element that caused to fire this function. This is the code example:

```
function aaa (id) {
  console.log(id);
}


jQuery('#inputStreet').on('input', _.throttle(aaa(event.target.id), 2000));
```

The console says that it cannot read property 'target' of undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `_.throttle` a function, not the *result* of a function call.

```
jQuery('#inputStreet').on('input', _.throttle(function(event){
    aaa(event.target.id);
}, 2000));
```